# Delegate method is being called but doesn't execute properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, delegates

I'm having a problem with one of my delegate methods. I have a collectionViewController to which I have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, which is calling a delegate method `fadeOutLabels` in my UICollectionViewCell. I can confirm the delegate method being called by a NSLog statement `NSLog(@"fadeOutLabels was called");`. But the other code inside that function isn't being executed. I'm quite sure I'm missing something completely obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out myself. Code as follows:

FOFPhotoCell.h

```
@protocol FOFPhotoCellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)fadeOutLabels;

@end


@interface FOFPhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    id delegate;
}


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FOFPhotoCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *photo;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *fetchPhotos;

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;





@end
```

FOFPhotoCell.m

```
@implementation FOFPhotoCell

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        CGFloat widthFromBounds = self.contentView.bounds.size.width;

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.imageView atIndex:0];


        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, widthFromBounds, 60)];
        self.titleLabel = titleLabel;
        self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.3];
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self.contentView insertSubview:self.titleLabel atIndex:1];

    }
    return self;

}

-(void)fadeOutLabels
{
    NSLog(@"fadeOutLabels was called");


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0  /* do not add a delay because we will use performSelector. */
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^ {
                         self.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];

                     }];

    }
```

FOFPhotosViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FOFPhotoCell.h"

@interface FOFPhotosViewController : UICollectionViewController <FOFPhotoCellDelegate>


@end
```

FOFPhotosViewController.m

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FOFPhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *photosArray = [self.dishes valueForKeyPath:@"avatar_url"];
    NSArray *nameArray = [self.dishes valueForKeyPath:@"name"];


//    NSLog(@"photoURL %@", _responseDictionary);
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xx.yy.zz.qq:4000%@",[photosArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]]]];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];




    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapAndHold = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:@selector(fadeOutLabels)];

    tapAndHold.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapAndHold];



    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];

    return cell;
}
```

I would really appreciate if some one could help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Can you show the part where you init your long press recognizer ? Have you tried to set a breakpoint on line `self.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0;` ?

Comment: The long press g.recognizer is initialised in my FOFPhotosViewController.m (should be the 5th line from the bottom). What would I be looking for by setting a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%@",self);` after `NSLog(@"fadeOutLabels was called");` and print the result ?

Comment: I get the following output:
``2014-04-08 14:40:22.917 DSK[83147:60b] <FOFPhotoCell: 0x10977d790; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (683.5 683; 340.5 340.5); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x10977d8d0>>``

Comment: Of course, don't know why I didn't think of that... Thank you very much @Justafinger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from the LongPressGestureRecognizer that should be instantiated in your custom cell and not in your view controller.

Basically, if you have a hundred cell how the long press gesture recognizer is supposed to know which cell you have pressed and which label to fade out.

You can try this instead, in your custom cell :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapAndHold = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fadeOutLabels)];

        tapAndHold.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapAndHold];
        ....
    }
}
```

And of course remove those lines in the view controller.